# Building json-array with all image information before sending it with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So, I made a HUGE form, with lots of categories. One of them has to have all the images I previewed on my web page.

Since it is a huge form I prefer building my own json instead of using serialize, or serializeArray(). After that I send it with ajax.

So each time I chose a file, I want to add it to an array (allfiles). I don't seem to find out how I can add all the information needed by php into that array for each image.

HTML (the real form) :

```
 <form class="form-horizontal well imgForm" method="post" action="process_form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="contenu" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Choose images</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="file" multiple="true"  class="form-control" name="image" accept="image/*">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group all_img" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
      <div id="image_preview" class="col-lg-6 image_preview sr-only">
       <div class="thumbnail hidden">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/5" alt="">                               
          <div class="caption">
            <h4></h4>
            <p></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger delete_img">Annuler</button></p>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>

     </div>


</form>
```

jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      //notyTada('blaaa'  ,'warning');

      /* cloning img */
      var imageprev = $('.image_preview').clone();
   /* THIS IS THE ARRAY THAT WILL BE SEND VIA AJAX, SUPPOSE TO CONTAIN ALL MY IMAGES */ 
   var allfiles = [];
      // EVERY TIME YOU ADD A FILE 
    $('.imgForm').find('input[name="image"]').on('change', function (e) {
        var files = $(this)[0].files;
        if (files.length > 0) {

            var file = files[0],
                $image_preview = imageprev.clone().removeClass('sr-only').appendTo('.all_img');

          allfiles.push(file);
          /* TRYING TOO SEE IF THERE IS SOMETHING */
             console.log(JSON.stringify(allfiles));


          // Ici on injecte les informations recoltées sur le fichier pour l'utilisateur
            $image_preview.find('.thumbnail').removeClass('hidden');
            $image_preview.find('img').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
            $image_preview.find('h4').html(file.name);
            $image_preview.find('.caption p:first').html(file.size +' bytes');
        }

    });

    // Bouton "Annuler" pour vider le champ d'upload
    $(document).on('click','.delete_img',function(){
        //$('.imgForm').find('input[name="image"]').val('');
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });
  });
```

[preview on code pen](http://codepen.io/golgie/pen/gryVkq) 
Choose an image, it will show an empty array in alert. This array is suppose to have the information of the image.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see in the JSON? Right now you're trying to serialize a `File`, but that's not a JSON serializable object. You'll need to pick what properties you want to send to the server and put those in your array.

Comment: Well i need to send the  name, type ,tmp_name and error,size of the file.

Comment: Can you define "type", "tmp_name", and "error"? What are those?

Comment: On my server side i need $_FILE['tmp_name'] $_FILE['error'] as found on this documentation : https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.post-method.php.

Comment: Well then you'll have to actually submit a form with the files in it... no JSON array will make that work. (`tmp_name` is set by PHP when it saves the actual bytes of the file to the server. For that to happen, the file needs to actually be sent.)

Comment: Even if i put all the information in a formData object ? like this : http://blog.w3villa.com/websites/uploading-filesimage-with-ajax-jquery-without-submitting-a-form/

Comment: Yes, that should work (on some browsers), but sending JSON will not.

Comment: Oke i will try that, thanks